# The initialization process in Dymola and Start attribute uses

Tags: modelica, dymola

For a simple model in Dymola, the Start attribute works to provide initial conditions for the DOE equations, like the following examples.

```
model QuiescentModelUsingStart "Find steady-state solutions to LotkaVolterra equations"
  parameter Real alpha=0.1 "Reproduction rate of prey";
  parameter Real beta=0.02 "Mortality rate of predator per prey";
  parameter Real gamma=0.4 "Mortality rate of predator";
  parameter Real delta=0.02 "Reproduction rate of predator per prey";
  Real x(start=10) "Prey population";
  Real y(start=10) "Predator population";
initial equation
  der(x) = 0;
  der(y) = 0;
equation
  der(x) = x*(alpha-beta*y);
  der(y) = y*(delta*x-gamma);
end QuiescentModelUsingStart;
```

But for the complicated model like a power plant model, which is a strong nonlinear model, it is a lot more complicated.

[image]

Based on the Modelica by example(https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/equations/variables/), the start attribute may also be used as an initial guess if the variable has been chosen as an iteration variable.

So, what is the process of initializing a model in Dymola? Would Dymola take the "equation" part into consideration during initialization, and set the derivate as zero, so it could Find the Steady-State as Initial Conditions?

Or Dymola just uses the "start attributes" and "initial equation" part to get a group of initial values?

How should I ensure that the initialization values I use could make up a steady-state?
[image]

Comment: You can actually initialize the derivatives with zero in the initial equations section. During initialization all regular equations and all initial equations are used and all algebraic variables, state derivatives and also the states are unknowns, just as @Markus described.You don't need to directly initialize states if the system resulting from your added initial equations is regular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably an excerpt from the [Modelica Language Specification](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf) describes what you are looking for:

> Before any operation is carried out with a Modelica model [e.g., simulation or linearization], initialization takes place to assign consistent values for all variables present in the model. During this phase, also the derivatives, der(..), and the pre-variables, pre(..), are interpreted as unknown algebraic variables. The initialization uses all equations and algorithms that are utilized in the intended operation [such as simulation or linearization].

This is the first part of Section 8.6, which is about three pages and should give you a pretty good insight on what happens during initialization. It also discusses the `start` attribute with `fixed=true/false`.